# Subtract column value from each element in a list from another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Column `mean_values` contains lists of values. The number of elements varies. Column `median` contains a single value. I want to create column `new_list` that contains a list of elements (original mean - median). I want to iterate over the original list, subtract the median and put all values in a new list/column.

Sample dataframe:

- mean_values : [2,2,3,6,7]
- median : 3

Expected output:

- new_list : [1,1,0,3,4]

Tried:

```
def subfunc(x,m):
  x = x-m
  return abs(x)

table['new_list'] = table['mean_values'].apply(lambda x: list(map(subfunc,x,table['median'])))
```

This works for the first element in the list, but once it reaches the second it subtracts the median value from the next row and so on. I want it to continue to subtract the median from the current row from each element.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample input and expected output? (in text form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
df["new_list"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [abs(x["median"] - v) for v in x["mean_values"]], axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       mean_values  median         new_list
0  [2, 2, 3, 6, 7]       3  [1, 1, 0, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made this much harder than it needs to be.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([2,2,3,6,7],columns=['means'])
median = df['means'].median()
df['new']  = (df['means'] - median).abs()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   means  new
0      2  1.0
1      2  1.0
2      3  0.0
3      6  3.0
4      7  4.0
```